# Delete a comment from a post: comment won't delete or wrong comment deleted, commentId undefined

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, put, populate

I'm trying to allow a user to delete a comment from a post. The code I currently have returns no deleted post: { n: 0, ok: 1, deletedCount: 0 }. If I change `_id` to `id` in comments.js, it will delete a comment but always only the oldest (first) comment. The commentId shows undefined in the backend either way.

Here are my models:

```
// Comment Model
    user: 
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        }, 
    comment: {type: String, required: true}
}



// Post Model
{
description: String, 
user: 
  {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
comments: [
     {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Comment"
    }]
}
```

Frontend mapping of comments and delete button:

```
const commentList = (
      <>
    {props.post.comments && props.post.comments
    .map(comment => {
       
        let deleteComment = commentId => {
            axios
            .put(`/api/comments/${props.postId}`, {commmentId: commentId})
            .then(() => {
                console.log('-------deleted: ', commentId, '------------------')
                props.getSinglePost()
                props.getAllPosts()
            })
        }


        return (
          <div key={comment._id}>
            <p>{comment.comment}</p>
            {comment.user.username === props.user.username? <button onClick={()=> deleteComment(comment._id)}>delete comment</button> : <p>{comment.user.username}</p>}
          </div>
        );
      })}
  </>
)
```

comments route:

```
router.put('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    const commentId = req.body.commentId;
    console.log("commmentId", commentId) // undefined
    Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $pull: {comments: commentId}})
    .then(commentedPost => {   
        res.json(commentedPost);
        
        return Comment.deleteOne({ _id: commentId}) /// id ???
        .then(data => {
            console.log("Deleted in comments.js ROUTE: ", data) 
        })
        .catch(err => {
            next(err)
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.json(err)
    })
})
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be related to your problem directly, but creating the `deleteComment` function inside the map where you return the JSX is incredibly inefficient. Its creating a new function for every element in the array. Move it outside into the component body.

Comment: The problem seems to be a typo. "commmentId" has an extra "m" in the put body.

Comment: It was definitely the typo causing the issue. I also moved the function outside the map. Thanks so much for helping me, React is new and I spent like a week looking for my error thinking it was in the logic :) It all works now better than ever!